# Running Example App using Flutter in Android Emulator

Tags: android, flutter

I'm trying to run a Flutter example in an Android Emulator.
The project that I'm running is: https://github.com/iampawan/Flutter-UI-Kit

When I run it I get the following error:

```
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> /Users/R/dev/flutter-projects/learn/Flutter-UI-Kit/android/key.properties (No such file or directory)
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
BUILD FAILED in 0s
  Command: /Users/R/dev/flutter-projects/learn/Flutter-UI-Kit/android/gradlew app:properties
Please review your Gradle project setup in the android/ folder.
```

My flutter doctor -v output:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel master, v1.4.8-pre.24, on Mac OS X 10.14.4 18E226, locale ----)
    • Flutter version 1.4.8-pre.24 at /Users/R/dev/flutter-installation/sdk-git/flutter
    • Framework revision 976223533d (hace 2 días), 2019-03-31 07:38:41 -0400
    • Engine revision f3ec767458
    • Dart version 2.2.1 (build 2.2.1-dev.2.1 None)


[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /Users/R/Library/Android/sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-28, build-tools 28.0.3
    • ANDROID_HOME = /Users/R/Library/Android/sdk
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1248-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] iOS toolchain - develop for iOS devices (Xcode 10.2)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 10.2, Build version 10E125
    • ios-deploy 1.9.4
    • CocoaPods version 1.6.0

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.3)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin version 33.0.1
    • Dart plugin version 182.5215
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1248-b01)

[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2018.2.7)
    • IntelliJ at /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app
    • Flutter plugin version 33.0.1
    • Dart plugin version 182.5215

[✓] VS Code (version 1.32.3)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 2.25.0

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
    • Android SDK built for x86 • emulator-5554 • android-x86 • Android 9 (API 28) (emulator)

• No issues found!
```

Any help would be appreciated!

I already followed this solution: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/18983